# What is the cheapest way of travelling between New York and Las Vegas by public transportation?

Tags: air-travel, public-transport, new-york-city, las-vegas, christmas

I am looking for the **cheapest way of traveling** between **New York** and **Las Vegas** by public transport.I want to celebrate Christmas in Las Vegas this year.I can travel in trains, buses or any other easiest and cheapest way because an airplane ticket will be very costly for me.

Comment: Airplane will be cheaper than any other mode of transport if you buy in advance.

Comment: how much it cost?

Comment: It can be as little as $300 round trip if you book right now. Buses and trains will be way more expensive or will take a crazy amount of time. Or both. Probably both.

Comment: what is the cost of bus and train?

Comment: For concrete prices, do your own searches. [We are not a travel agency](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1445/the-wanta-debate-we-are-not-travel-agents).

Comment: Looks like minimum $280 and it'll take 85 hours with two transfers. But I picked random dates around Christmas which may not suit. Look on Amtrak and Greyhound websites.

Comment: @MuhammadTahseenurRehman You ask several times for prices, but the tools we have at our disposal for checking them are exactly the same ones that you have. We are not a travel agency here to suggest possible itineraries. Moreover, the total cost of a trip is not merely its fare, but all the ancillary costs— maybe you could hitchhike for free, but it would take you five days and cost five days' worth of meals, lodging, and foregone income and visiting time. Please [edit] your post to address these issues. The [help] will offer additional guidance.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Buses or trains will definitely take a crazy amount of time (2-3 days, most likely... LAS to NYC is over 2,500 miles by road [over 4,000 km.]) An airplane can do it in 4-5 hours. Not a tough choice.

Comment: What do you mean by "public transportation"? There are no public buses that will go this far, are you ok with private bus companies? Are we counting Amtrak as "public"?

Comment: @AzorAhai I mean, Amtrak is owned by the government A.K.A. the public...

Comment: @johnVonTrapp It is for-profit though, while my local bus and light rail systems are not.

Comment: Your local bus and light rail probably won't get you cross country, though. My local bus/light rail barely gets me cross *county*. For interstate travel, if you want *public* transit you'll have to look for *federally owned* transportation services.

Comment: @AzorAhai The word "public" in "public transportation" doesn't mean government-owned or not-for-profit. It means available to the general public, and thus includes privately owned transportation services that anyone can use.

Comment: @RossRidge I have most often heard it used to refer to publically owned services. In any case, that only makes the OP's need to clarify more obvious, as under your definition, airlines would be included.

Comment: @AzorAhai The poster's intent seems to be clear. He's looking for the cheapest form of public transportation, and is only excluding airplanes because of an (probably incorrect) assumption that this would be not be the cheapest option. Since both answers posted so far are consistent with this interpretation, I don't see the need for clarification.

Comment: @RossRidge My point is mainly about the title. It should match the body. He's not looking for the cheapest *public transportation* (by anyone's definition), he's either looking for a) the cheapest way to get to LV without flying or b) the cheapest way to get to LV without driving.

Comment: @AzorAhai There's no reason to assume that the poster wouldn't be willing to fly by plane if that proves to be the cheapest option, as appears to be the case.

Comment: rome2rio.com is the definitive site for questions like this.

Comment: **_Walking_** is clearly the cheapest way. You can still make it till Christmas, easily (Google Maps estimates 35 days). Are there any other time constraints?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a link to [a good site that compares costs and times of different modes of travel](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/New-York/Las-Vegas) between different places. It doesn't always know about every single special offer, but it's very good at giving a general view of pricing and time.

As you can see, in your case (and not considering dates)

- You can fly for around $200 taking 8 hours
- You can take train and bus for around $500 taking 2 days
- You can take the bus for around $350, taking 2 days

Comment: In addition it's worth looking at what companies/airlines it suggests and then going directly to their websites to investigate further. For example, the train+bus route is discounted 25% for the holidays if you book directly with Amtrak.

Answer (score 1):

While a cross-country Amtrak trip is on my bucket list, taking a train is not going to be your cheapest travel option, in terms of time and money. The train is going to take literal days each way, and is going to cost a few hundred. If you then add on the cost of meals on the train, you're looking at another hundred. I'm sure a bus is going to be about the same, but it will be extremely uncomfortable and miserable.

In this current economy, and with your itinerary, flying is going to be your cheapest option. If you want prices and specifics you can try that really cool website @DJClayworth linked, or [flights.google.com](https://flights.google.com) for flight prices and whatnot.